# Combine Ids to a single field

Tags: design, database, rdbms

I would like to ask if there is any powerful method we can use to combine the Id's to a single field for faster search and retrieval.

My case is like this, I have a table that stores ID's of companies.

---

ID |  CompanyName

---

1 |  Company A

2 | Company B

3 | Company C

I have another table where there is data that need to be processed by these companies. so i am looking for a better method to find the data that is not processed by a specific company.

---

Data  | CompaniesProcessed

---

A | 1,2

B | 3,2

C | 3

one easy way i can think is store the company ID's as a separated value and search for it. The data set to search can be huge, so,  Is there any other way that will be faster for search rather than the string operation?

---

**EDIT:** I need to read through data and check if it is already processed for a specific company. so if this is linked table i have to do a read operation of data and search the linked table to know if it is processed. However, if it is in a single table, i can just filter out those records that are processed while i read.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use a link table? Also, please define "huge".

Comment: yea, there is. i will edit the question.

Comment: Are you aware that, when using a link table **with proper indexes**, the "filtering" is done by the database in an efficient manner? For example, when you want to check if data record A (with ID=10) is already processed for company B (with ID=2), you use something like `SELECT ... FROM LinkTable WHERE DataID=10 AND CompanyID=2` and check if the resultset is empty or not. This requires a combined index on `(DataID,CompanyID)` to be efficient.

Comment: so linked table will be most efficient way here? I just wanted to know if we have some other option available or not.

Comment: There is no "most efficient way" in general. You need to know the number and type of expected queries, what "huge data set" means, and your performance requirements. And you should also consider that "performance" is not the only non-functional requirement you have to take into account, extendibility or making things consistent may be also important. Then you can try out what works best and measure. For a purely sequential batch processing, storing a list of IDs in just one column, as you proposed, can turn out to be the fastest way *for exactly that process*, in exactly this situation, ...

Comment: ... but maybe you have other use cases to consider, which will slow down, or become error-prone, when you do not use proper foreign-key constraints (which is not possible when you store IDs as comma-separated strings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a many-to-many relationship and you can model it with an intermediate table, which contains the relationships between Companies and Data.

So, you will have 3 tables:

---

### ID | CompanyName

1  | Company A

2  | Company B

3  | Company C

---

### ID | CompanyData

10 | A

20 | B

30 | C

---

### DataID | CompanyID

10     | 1

10     | 2

20     | 2

20     | 3

30     | 3

Now you can query very efficiently what companies use Data A, or what data company 2 uses and it will be a lot faster than searching ids within a string.

---

EDIT

As Doc Brown correctly says in a comment, in order to make this approach work optimally, specially for queries involving non Primary Key columns, proper indexing needs to be in place.

Comment: yea, this is true. But I remember somewhere i saw using a single column with some arithmetical operation instead of string operation to identify the ID's involved.

Comment: In the question, i just gave a simple example of my actual problem. In my actual case, I need to read through data and check if it is already processed for a specific company. so if this is separate tables i have to do a read operation + a search operation. However, if it is in a single table, i can just filter out those records that are processed while i read.

Comment: Well, the many-to-many table is a lot more powerful than what I wrote in my answer. You can add more columns. For example, "IsProcessed", or, instead of removing an association, you can add an AssociationEnabled, so you can switch it on and off, and so on. So, searching companies with Data A, which are Enabled and Not Processed is still very efficient.

Comment: ok, agreed. I will be following this way. but is there no other efficient way of using a single column?